# SOLR substring search using sunspot_rails and heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, solr, sunspot-rails

I recently altered my schema.xml (as suggested by this post in the [sunspot wiki](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Wildcard-searching-with-ngrams)) to help with substring searching. This works great locally. But after pushing to production and reindexing, the changes don't appear to have taken effect (i.e. substring matching doesn't seem to work). In other words, if I take the same string (i.e. "Mastercard") and search "Ma" locally, I get a "Mastercard" string as a result... but on production, I don't get anything. I'm using the sunspot_rails gem on heroku.

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with the websolr instance not properly restarting?

Comment: could you restart solr completely? so new schema.xml will be used as normal

Comment: @Mysterion well the trick here is that i'm not running my own solr server (using websolr through heroku), so stopping and then starting a new instance just pulls up the default schema.xml instead of what I really wanted. turns out websolr does offer a schema.xml editor, though.

Comment: Nice. Please add this as answer, so question will be answered and other people could find the answer.

Comment: Yup, I'll add it as an answer in 7 hours (when stackoverflow lets me.... because I don't have any reputation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. My app's schema.xml file didn't touch the websolr instance, which has its own schema.xml (editable through the "advanced configuration" tab). Made the change there and now everything works as expected. Awesome.